# Viewing Images in WebView

Tags: android

I am using an android webView to load a url.  This url refers to a standard JSP page where various images are loaded using a simple java servlet to query a database and return blobs as response.outputstreams.

When viewing the jsp pages in a standard browers everything works fine but when I try to view the same page using a webview, none of the images are displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have in your AndroidManifest.xml internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and enable Javascript in your webview

```
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```